# In Sim City 4, what does the "obliterate city" animation supposed to represent?

Tags: simcity-4

Having spent countless hours building, developing and managing cities in Sim City 4, one element of the game has always perplexed me.

Whenever a player decides to destroy a city and start from scratch, upon clicking on the "obliterate city" option, the city doesn't simply disappear, but instead is preceded by a very eerie [animation sequence of star-like lights appearing in the sky, coupled with bright flashes of white light and hauntingly creepy sound effects.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjTj4AHCJnI)

What are those floating stars and flashes of light supposed to be? A nuclear explosion? Some sort of divine apocalypse? Or maybe a reference to something?

Comment: I doubt we'd ever be able to answer this; only the developers would know for sure.

Comment: @Frank Worth a try though!

Comment: It is possible that it is some sort of apocalypse

Comment: Perhaps meant to represent bombs falling and destroying the city?  (I'm thinking the explosion graphics are deliberately abstracted in order to maintain an "E for Everyone" rating from the ESRB.)  I was trying to determine if there was a pattern to the explosions, but there doesn't appear to be - one happens in the middle of a field, others are taking out buildings seemingly at random.